# Google Assitant calling webhook

Tags: actions-on-google

How i can call web hook after user input and send input in web-hook on my own server and send response to Google

> Blockquote

assitant display

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Actions Builder in the Actions Console, you will set up a webhook selection in the intent handlers (or the **On Enter** event).

In the screenshot below, I have an example scene *TestScene*. You see that when the intent *stay* is matched, I have checked the **Call your webhook** option, which will call my webhook with the handler `my_handler_name`. Then my webhook can [process the request and generate a response](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs), which will be returned to the user.

[image]